# Check in object array if the length of groups is greater than zero in a OF element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects. Inside this object I have an array of groups that determine the quantity.

There is a way to check within the object array if the groups is greater than zero where the OF element is equal to 12.2.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vxvzgv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**what I tried**

```
Sort = [
    {
      id: 1,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 's',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: [
        {
          type: 'type1',
          quant: 21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 'M',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      of: 2.2,
      tam: 'L',
      name: 'Works',
      groups: []
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.Sort)
    var x = this.Sort.forEach(element => {
      if(element.of == 12.2){
        if(element.groups.length > 0){
          return true;
        }
        else{
          return false;
        }
      }
      
    });
    console.log(x)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` ignores the return value and executes for all the elements. So it would be both easier and more performant to use `some()` ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)) instead, e.g.

```
const exists = this.Sort.some(s => s.of === 12.2 && s.groups.length > 0);
```

If you want to use forEach anyway, you could place your boolean value outside of the loop with initial value of `false`, and then set it's value to true only if the element exists, e.g.

```
let exists = false;
this.Sort.forEach(e => {
  if (e.of === 12.2 && e.groups.length > 0) {
    exists = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just posting without angular part to run and see the output

```js
Sort = [
    {
      id: 1,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 's',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: [
        {
          type: 'type1',
          quant: 21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 'M',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      of: 2.2,
      tam: 'L',
      name: 'Works',
      groups: []
    }
  ];


  console.log(this.Sort)
  var x = this.Sort.filter(element => element.of === 12.2 && element.groups.length >0);
  console.log("Filtered Output")
  console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  Sort = [
    {
      id: 1,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 's',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: [
        {
          type: 'type1',
          quant: 21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 'M',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      of: 2.2,
      tam: 'L',
      name: 'Works',
      groups: []
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.Sort);
    let groupLengthList = [];
    for (const data of this.Sort) {
      if (data.of === 12.2) {
        if (data.groups.length > 0) {
          groupLengthList.push(true);
        } else {
          groupLengthList.push(false);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(groupLengthList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) protoype will do the job:

```js
let Sort = [
    {
      id: 1,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 's',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: [
        {
          type: 'type1',
          quant: 21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      of: 12.2,
      tam: 'M',
      name: 'Color Run',
      groups: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      of: 2.2,
      tam: 'L',
      name: 'Works',
      groups: []
    }
  ];

let res = Sort.filter(e => e.of == 12.2 && e.groups.length > 0);

console.log(res)
```